# Can I present statements from two different accounts as proof of funds?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm planning to visit a Schengen country and for visa purposes they require me to produce bank statement for 6 months. I can't find any information in the official website regarding the fact whether I can include statements from different accounts. I recently opened a new account and, by the time I want to get my visa, the best I can produce is 4 to 5 months of bank statement. Also note that it is my salary account.

Can I include the statements from my previous account as a bank statement for the first 1-2 months? For first 2 months proof, I will include bank statement from X account and for the rest of the 4 months from Y account, making the total to be 6 months.

I have found information that I can produce multiple statements in other answers but this seems to be a bit different as in those all of their accounts had been open for more than 6 months or either not mentioned.

Also I have been using both of the accounts, that is both the accounts are still active, but the old one only as a secondary.

Comment: Does the closing balance of your old account statement match the opening balance of your new account statement, and show a single transfer out/in? If so, I’d say ‘yes’ because there is a complete audit trail between the two accounts.

Comment: Not really, I have been using both of the accounts. The old not so much though, only because its been saved at so many places. And thanks for the edit, @Traveller.

Comment: In general it must be best to give the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth so I would give them everything you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that the officer is looking for when they look at your bank statements:

- Does your income and expenses match what you have stated in the application, and what you have provided as other documentation? For example, does the salary you mention actually get deposited in the account?
- Does the account activity have any suspicious transactions? For example, are there any large unexplained deposits? This can be an evidence of funds parking, which is a way to "pad" your balance in hopes of showing a strong finance position than what you hold.
- Are the costs of the trip going to be a financial burden for you? For example, you state in your application that you are paying for the hotel, the airplane ticket and will be supporting yourself. If the average sum required for this (and it differs per country) a significant percentage of your income? If so, you may be at risk of not being able to support yourself.

So, if you mention in your employment letter that you have started your job 4 months ago with X salary and the same X salary is deposited in  your new account, this is fine.

If you know that the balance and activities in your new account are not sufficient for the purposes of demonstrating your financial position, you can submit statements of your other accounts.

Keep in mind it is very common for people to have a savings account and a current (or salary) account. They often submit statements of both as proof of accessible funds; so the officers are used to seeing multiple bank statements from applicants.